# Wordpress: How can I get a bookmark by name?

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, bookmarks

I know how to get a bookmark in wordpress by the bookmark id.

```
<?php $bookmark = get_bookmark(8); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $bookmark->link_url; ?>" target="_new">link</a>
```

How can I get it by its name instead of its id?

Thank you.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I dont think `rendering` is the right term here. :P

Comment: Na, I asked what is the HTML getting **generated**, may be... :)

Comment: The rendering doesn't matter. The bookmark link of id '8' has 'PUB1' as name. I want to get it by 'PUB1' so if the link is erased (by an user error) the user just have to restore the link and code has not to be rewritten to change the fixed id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well apart from using the `$wpdb` with an SQL-query directly you could use the `search`-option of [`get_bookmarks`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bookmarks):

```
$bookmarks = get_bookmarks(array('search' => 'link_name name'));
```

But it searches not only the link_name field but also other fields:

> Searches link_url, link_name or link_description like the search string

Answer (score 1):

```
           <?php 

           $links = get_bookmarks( array('category' => "136"));
            foreach ( $links as $link ) {
            $linkname = $link->link_name;
            if ( substr($linkname, 0, 1) == "C"){
            echo '<ul><li><a title="'.$link->link_description.'" href="'.$link->link_url.'" target="_blank"></li></ul>';
            echo $link->link_name.'</a> <br/> ';}
            }

           ?>
```